# Ansible Nested Loop for Cisco ACL

Tags: networking, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, cisco

I'm creating a playbook for an ACL update, where the existing ACL needs to be updated, but before adding the new set of IP addresses to that ACL, I need to make sure that the ACL is present and that the IP hasn't already been configured.

**Process:**

Need to add the below IP addresses
[image]

**ACL NAME:** 11, 13, DATA_TEST, dummy

1. Check if the list of ACL are present

commands: "show access-lists {{item}}"

[image: > Blockquote]

2. Check if ACL Exist

**Q:** Can't figure out how to access each item in the result of the first action to see if ACL has been configured. Ex. We can see from the output that dummy has no output, how can I exclude that and process if exist.  (refer code below)

3. Check if IP addresses already added

**Q:** What is the best approach here? I'm thinking using when then comparing the ACL output from stdout vs the given variables content (ex. parents/lines)?

4. Add the set of IP addresses on target ACL

**Q:** What is the best approach here? Need to match the ACL name and configure using the variable.
If somebody is knowledgeable about Ansible, perhaps you could assist me in creating this project? I'm still doing some research, so any assistance you can give would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

My Code:

```
---
- name: Switch SVU
  hosts: Switches
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    my_acl_list:
      - 11
      - 13
      - DATA_TEST
      - dummy
    fail: "No such access-list {{item}}"
    UP_ACL11:
      parents:
        - access-list 11 permit 192.168.1.4
        - access-list 11 permit 192.168.1.5
    UP_ACL13:
      parents: access-list 13 permit 10.22.1.64 0.0.0.63
    UP_ACLDATA:
      lines:
        - permit 172.11.1.64 0.0.0.63
        - permit 172.12.2.64 0.0.0.63
      parents: ip access-list standard DATA_TEST


  tasks:
    - name: Check if the ACL Name already exists.
      ios_command:
        commands: "show access-lists {{item}}"
      register: acl_result
      loop: "{{my_acl_list}}"   
    
    - debug: msg="{{acl_result}}"

    - name: Check if ACL Exist
      debug:
        msg: "{{item.stdout}}"
      when: item.stdout.exists
      with_items: "{{acl_result.results}}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{item.item}}"
      # Pending - Need to know how to match if ACL name exist on stdout.

    - name: Check if IP addresses already added
      set_fact:
      when: 
        # pending - ansible lookup?
        # when var: UP_ACL11, UP_ACL13, UP_ACLDATA IPs are not in ACL then TRUE

    - name: Add the set of IP addresses on target ACL
      ios_config:
        # pending - if doest exist on particular ACL name then configure using the var: UP_ACL11, UP_ACL13, UP_ACLDATA
```

Comment: [edit] the question and provide [mre]. See below. Other questions are not clear. What are the expected results?

Answer (score 2):

Given the simplified data for testing

```yaml
    acl_result:
      results:
        - item: DATA_TEST
          stdout:
            - "Standard ... 10 permit ... 20 permit ..."
          stdout_lines:
            - - "Standard ..."
              - "10 permit ..."
              - "20 permit ..."
        - item: dummy
          stdout:
            - ""
          stdout_lines:
            - - ""
```

---

Q: ***"Check if ACL Exists"***

A: If ACL doesn't exist the attribute *stdout* is a list of empty strings. Test it

```yaml
    - name: Check if ACL Exists
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.item }} exists: {{ item.stdout|map('length')|select()|length > 0 }}"
      loop: "{{ acl_result.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{item.item}}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [Check if ACL Exists] ********************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=DATA_TEST) => 
  msg: 'DATA_TEST exists: True'
ok: [localhost] => (item=dummy) => 
  msg: 'dummy exists: False'
```

---

Notes:

- In the filter [*select*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.select), *"If no test is specified, each object will be evaluated as a boolean"*. The number `0` evaluates to `false`.
- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    acl_result:
      results:
        - item: DATA_TEST
          stdout:
            - "Standard ... 10 permit ... 20 permit ..."
          stdout_lines:
            - - "Standard ..."
              - "10 permit ..."
              - "20 permit ..."
        - item: dummy
          stdout:
            - ""
          stdout_lines:
            - - ""

  tasks:

    - name: Check if ACL Exists
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.item }} exists: {{ item.stdout|map('length')|select()|length > 0 }}"
      loop: "{{ acl_result.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{item.item}}"
```

- The test can be simplified if you're sure *stdout* is a list with a single line only

```yaml
        msg: "{{ item.item }} exists: {{ item.stdout|first|length > 0 }}"
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to provide the solution.

Comment: But I'd like to understand the solution. According to what I understand, the result is looped, and the method is by looping the item and the item contained within it (ACL Name) using loop control. On the other hand, we print using debug/msg: item.item if content existing on item.stdout.

Comment: The *loop_control label* is irrelevant. It simplifies the output only. The boolean expression is what you need. [edit] the question and make it [mre] if you have a problem.

Comment: Thanks, Any idea how I can process the output if True and add a condition if False? I tried adding this code in variable  "{{ item.item }} exists: {{ item.stdout|first|length > 0 }}" but somehow can't get the target output

Comment: how can I use when for this?  when: "{{ item.item }} exists: {{ item.stdout|first|length > 0 }}"